# How do I do something when an animation finishes?

Tags: android, animation, android-3.1-honeycomb

I have an `ImageView` that I use to show progress via an `AnimationDrawable`.  When I want to show my progress spinner, I do this:

```
animDrawable.start();
ObjectAnimator.ofFloat(view, "alpha", 1.0f).setDuration(300).start();
```

When I want to hide the spinner, I do this:

```
ObjectAnimator.ofFloat(view, "alpha", 0.0f).setDuration(300).start();
animDrawable.stop();
```

However, this has the effect that the animation stops immediately.  I would like it to stop only after the `ObjectAnimator` has completely faded to 0.0 alpha.  Is there a way I can setup something along the lines of an "AnimationCompleted" callback?

Comment: Couldn't you sleep the thread for the duration, then call .stop()?

Comment: I'd rather not sleep the UI thread.  I could do a postDelayed() Runnable, but that seems very hacky.  I suspect there is a correct way to do this.  Furthermore, I'm not sure how accurate the whole duration thing is.

Comment: You could have the runnable check the alpha at a satisfying interval

Comment: There is no interval that will satisfy me.

Answer (score 53, accepted):

The more modern way of doing this is to use the [`ViewPropertyAnimator`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/ViewPropertyAnimator.html):

```
view.animate()
    .alpha(0f)
    .withEndAction(new Runnable() {
      @Override
      public void run() {
        // Do something.
      }
    })
    .start();
```

Or, if you're using RetroLambda:

```
view.animate()
    .alpha(0f)
    .withEndAction(() -> {
      // Do something.
    })
    .start();
```

Comment: As a side note thats perfect solution for single view, for multiple views there is no clean solution of using ex. AnimatorSet and ViewPropertyAnimator's.

Answer (score 20):

To your original question about the ObjectAnimator object you can set up an Animator.AnimatorListener object which defines several animation state callbacks.  You want to override public void onAnimationEnd(Animator animation)

```
animation.addListener(new Animator.AnimatorListener() {
                @Override
                public void onAnimationStart(Animator animation) {

                }

                @Override
                public void onAnimationEnd(Animator animation) {
                    Toast.makeText(VideoEditorActivity.this, "animation ended", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }

                @Override
                public void onAnimationCancel(Animator animation) {

                }

                @Override
                public void onAnimationRepeat(Animator animation) {

                }
            });
```

Comment: From my own experience `.onAnimationEnd` has proven to be very unreliable. I would recommend @i_am_jorf answer using `.withEndAction(...)`

Answer (score 10):

**With androidx you can use doOnEnd method which invoked when the animation has ended**

```
val anim = ObjectAnimator.ofFloat(eva_image, View.TRANSLATION_Y, 0f, 500f)
anim.setDuration(500)
anim.doOnEnd { Toast.makeText(this, "Anim End", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show() }
anim.start()
```

Comment: Can't find this doOnEnd method.

Answer (score 1):

You could also look into postOnAnimation(Runnable)

Link to Docs: [postOnAnimation(java.lang.Runnable)](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#postOnAnimation(java.lang.Runnable))

Answer (score 0):

You can use this code with Object animator on Kotlin

```
ObjectAnimator.ofInt(
                view,
                "alpha",
                1.0f
            ).apply {
                duration = 300
                // some other params here
                doOnEnd { // your logic when the animation ended }
                start()
            }
```