# Android spinner close

Tags: android, view, spinner, handler

I have an activity with a spinner, and I was wondering if it is possible to close the spinner programmatically, if the user has opened it.

The whole story is that in the background I am running a process on a separate thread. When the process has finished, I invoke a Handler on the main activity and, depending on the outcome, I perform some tasks. It is then that I want to close the spinner, it the user has opened it.

The spinner is in the main.xml layout:

```
<Spinner android:id="@+id/birthPlaceSpinner" android:layout_weight="1" 
android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:prompt="@string/select"
android:layout_width="fill_parent" />
```

and this is the Handler:

```
private class BirthplaceChangedHandler extends Handler {

    @Override
    public void handleMessage(Message msg) {
        String placeFilterStr = birthPlaceFilterText.getText().toString();
        if ("".equals(placeFilterStr) || placeFilterStr == null || validNewAddresses.isEmpty()) {
            birthPlaceSpinner.setEnabled(false);
            hideGeoLocationInformation();
        } else {
            birthPlaceSpinner.setEnabled(true);
        }
        adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(getApplicationContext(), R.layout.multiline_spinner_dropdown_item, validNewAddressesStr)
        birthPlaceSpinner.setAdapter(adapter);
    }
}
```

Cheers!

Comment: How are you creating / starting the spinner?  What you want to do is almost certainly possible, but you haven't given enough information to answer your question.  Code snippets help.

Comment: Overriding `Spinner.onDetachedFromWindow`, making it public and calling manually was the only way which worked for me. I followed http://stackoverflow.com/a/21122845/369317

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I don't see a way to accomplish that -- there is no method on `Spinner` to close it. The "open" part of a `Spinner` is an `AlertDialog` on Android 1.x and 2.x, and I'm not completely sure how it is implemented on Honeycomb when using the holographic theme.

The only workaround would be to clone the source for `Spinner` and add in some code yourself to dismiss the dialog. But, again, it would not work on Honeycomb or higher until you can see and clone *that* code as well.

Beyond that, I would think that what you want is poor UX. If the user opened the `Spinner`, they are most likely actively examining the `Spinner`'s contents and making a selection. Yanking that out from under their finger will confuse them, at best. Please consider an alternative approach.

Also, don't use `getApplicationContext()` unless you know *why* you are using `getApplicationContext()`. You do not need or even want `getApplicationContext()` when creating an `ArrayAdapter`.

Answer (score 22):

```
  public static void hideSpinnerDropDown(Spinner spinner) {
    try {
        Method method = Spinner.class.getDeclaredMethod("onDetachedFromWindow");
        method.setAccessible(true);
        method.invoke(spinner);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 19):

This works for me:

```
class SomeAdapter extends BaseAdapter implements SpinnerAdapter {
    //......   
    public View getDropDownView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        View view = convertView;
        if (view == null) {
            //......
        }
        view.setOnClickListener(new ItemOnClickListener(parent));
        return view;
    }
    //.....
}
```

and the click listener:

```
class ItemOnClickListener implements View.OnClickListener {
    private View _parent;

    public ItemOnClickListener(ViewGroup parent) {
        _parent = parent;
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {
        //.......
        // close the dropdown
        View root = _parent.getRootView();
        root.dispatchKeyEvent(new KeyEvent(KeyEvent.ACTION_DOWN, KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK));
        root.dispatchKeyEvent(new KeyEvent(KeyEvent.ACTION_UP, KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK));
    }
}
```

Answer (score 10):

Well its a little complicated than I thought.

I am adding the step by step details here. Try to follow it. I was able to achieve this in api level 10.

**And this solution assumes that you are supposed to close the prompt dialog programatically when the user clicks on Home Button or If you had to move to next activity without user interaction**

The first step is to create a Custom Spinner by extending Spinner Class. 
Let's say, I have created a class called **CustomSpinner** in the package **com.bts.sampleapp**

My CustomSpinner class looks like this,

```
package com.bts.sampleapp;

import android.content.Context;
import android.util.AttributeSet;
import android.widget.Spinner;

    public class CustomSpinner extends Spinner{
        Context context=null;

        public CustomSpinner(Context context) {
            super(context);
            this.context=context;
        }

        public CustomSpinner(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyle) {
            super(context, attrs, defStyle);
        }

        public CustomSpinner(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
            super(context, attrs);
        }

        @Override
        public void onDetachedFromWindow() {
            super.onDetachedFromWindow();
        }
    }
```

Now in your Xml file, replace Spinner element by this custom spinner,

```
        <com.bts.sampleapp.CustomSpinner
        android:id="@+id/spin"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
```

The next step is to initialize and set adapter to this spinner in your Activity class,

```
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    CustomSpinner spin=null;
    spin=(CustomSpinner)findViewById(R.id.spin);
    spin.setAdapter(spinnerAdapter); //you can set your adapter here.
}
```

The final step is to close the dialog when the user clicks on HomeButton or When the Activity moves to background. To do this, we override the onPause() like this,

```
@Override
    protected void onPause() {
        Log.i("Life Cycle", "onPause");
        spin.onDetachedFromWindow();
        super.onPause();
    }
```

Now within the onPause() call the method `spin.onDetachedFromWindow();` which does the job of closing the prompt dialog for you.

**Now that being said,** calling `spin.onDetachedFromWindow();` from anywhere in your Activity should help you to close the spinner programatically. So if this is what you want, then remove the `onpause()`.

Answer (score 3):

I think you should scrap your use of `Spinner` and instead use an `ImageView` with a [Frame Animation](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/animation-resource.html#Frame) (i.e. `<animation-list>`) to create your own spinner.  You just set the `ImageView`'s background to be your Frame Animation drawable.

Then you can easily do something [like this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7274001/how-do-i-do-something-when-an-animation-finishes) to start and stop it.

Answer (score 2):

You would like to close your spinners from anywhere. Key injection for BACK pressed is the good solution but, here you are closing all the views at once.

How about setPressed(false)?
Link:
[Close Spinners dropdown when two among all in a groupview are clicked simultaneously](https://stackoverflow.com/q/24116724/787399)

Otherwise:
Try to make the Spinner `focusable` and `focusableInTouchMode`, and use `clearFocus()`
on it. Try to focus on the view below it using `requestFocus()` method.

Check if the spinner drop-down closes

Answer (score 0):

Use the `clearFocus()` to close the spinner programitically

```
spinner.clearFocus();
```

Answer (score 0):

Add clearfocus() in code.

```
Spinner spinner = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinner);
spinner.clearFocus();
```

Use transparent background in xml

```
android:background="@android:color/transparent

<Spinner 
    android:id="@+id/spinner"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@android:color/transparent"
    android:clickable="false"
    android:focusable="?android:attr/windowOverscan"
    android:focusableInTouchMode="false"
    android:pointerIcon="arrow"
    android:spinnerMode="dialog"
    android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light" />
```

Answer (score 0):

#### Koltin Reflection

```kotlin
fun AppCompatSpinner.dismiss() {
    val popup = AppCompatSpinner::class.java.getDeclaredField("mPopup")
    popup.isAccessible = true
    val listPopupWindow = popup.get(this) as ListPopupWindow
    listPopupWindow.dismiss()
}
```