# Hide the spinner list programmatically

Tags: java, android, spinner

I have used a spinner on a custom alert box. Once the alert pops up there is a spinner attached to it. And after the user clicks on the spinner it gives you a list of countries. And i am searching a way to remove/hide/dismiss that country list (Only the spinner list) programmatically. How to accomplish this?

My goal is to remove that country list which generated from the spinner, once the onPause of the activity invoked.

Comment: May i know y do u want to do that

Comment: Its because, if i open the spinner drop down list and put the app in background... after resuming the app from another 1 hr it gives a force close saying view not attached to the window.

Comment: You should put here some code. I suspect that your problem is not the spinner itself but rather in the creation/destruction of your Dialog. hiding it will not solve it.

Comment: now have you solution? i have same que. at this moment.. plzz share if u got the solution

Comment: Try this.. working for me http://stackoverflow.com/a/15723912/3485152

Answer (score 1):

You may hide the spinner by setting its visibility `GONE` or by making `setEnabled(false)`. But, that doesnt solve your problem i guess. You may have to override `onResume()` and `onPause()` methods for that.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to disable your spinner then it may helpful for you.
`Spinner.setEnabled(False);`

Answer (score 0):

Thank you guys. Dismissing the drop down list is not possible it seems. Tried several ways like dispatching beck key events, calling onbackpressed etc... Finally I removed the pop up dialog box (custom dialog) itself when the app goes to the background. Thank you so much for the help :)