# Android Spinner does not close after using setSelection()

Tags: android

I have a scenario where I want to programmatically change the value of my spinner using setSelection(). This works great, except that if the spinner is open (expanded?) an the time, the spinner does not close. Eg, the menu stays up, despite calling setSelection().

How can I programmatically close the spinner? I have tried performClick() to no avail.

---

edit: more details:

The reason I'm trying to do this is that my spinner actually uses a compound layout for each selection row. Namely, I have a linearlayout which contains an image, text, and button. The idea was that the button serves as an "edit" button (which opens an activity), while pressing on the image/text select the row (per usual).

The problem came when I added the button. Suddenly, the image & text no longer captured the press event to change the combo. In other words, adding a button to the row destroyed the touch-handling capacity of the entire row. So I tried to manually implement a click handler for the image/text, which subsequently executed a setSelection... which is where I ran into this problem.

Comment: Did you see this link? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7287195/android-spinner-close

Comment: Ah, despite a fair bit of googling I somehow missed that.

Comment: Just see if that link helps you. If yes then I could respond to your question and you can mark it as correct :)

Comment: @Antrromet No, it does not solve the problem.

Answer (score 1):

You say that after adding the button you lost the click handle on the entire row. Try adding this `android:descendantFocusability="blocksDescendants"` to your row layout, and see if you can get the clicks to work properly.