# Having trouble adding string array to spinner entries

Tags: android, arrays, android-spinner

What I'd like to accomplish is the String array names[] be what you see in the spinner, but I cannot seem to figure out how to do this. I have tried looking off of other similar questions, but everything I try results in a crash in my app, saying that it is unable to instantiate the activity. Below, I have included the onPostExecute, where I am generating the string array, and also my addListenerOnSpinnerSelection() method. Any guidance would be great.

```
protected void onPostExecute(JSONObject json) {
            try {
                // Get JSON Object
                JSONObject runes = json.getJSONObject(encodedId);

                // Get JSON Array node
                JSONArray rune = runes.getJSONArray("pages");

                // Loop through pages, page names stored in string array
                String[] name = new String[rune.length()];
                String curr;
                ArrayList<String> runePageNames = new ArrayList<String>();

                for(int i = 0; i < rune.length(); i++) {
                    JSONObject c = rune.getJSONObject(i);
                    name[i] = c.getString(TAG_NAME);
                    curr = c.getString(TAG_CURRENT);

                    if(curr.equals("true"))
                       name[i] = name[i] + " [Active]";
                    runePageNames.add(name[i]);

                    Log.i(".........", name[i]);
                }

                adapter = new ArrayAdapter(this,
                        android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item,
                        runePageNames);

                addListenerOnSpinnerSelection();

                // Set TextView
                textName.setText(name[0]);

            } catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }


    public void addListenerOnSpinnerSelection() {
            spinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {
                @Override
                public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int i, long l) {
                    ((TextView) adapterView.getChildAt(0)).setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#C49246"));
                    Toast.makeText(adapterView.getContext(),
                            "Page Selected: " + adapterView.getItemAtPosition(i).toString(),
                            Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                    page = adapterView.getItemAtPosition(i).toString();
                }

                @Override
                public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> adapterView) {

                }
            });
        }
```

Comment: Are you setting an adapter to your Spinner?

Comment: @joao2fast4u I have edited my code to include an adapter, but I am not sure of its placement in my code and if it is correct. It is also giving an error "cannot resolve constructor"

Comment: Try to pass YourActivity.this instead of this in `adapter = new ArrayAdapter(this,android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item,runePageNames);`

Comment: Maybe this will help you: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2784081/android-create-spinner-programmatically-from-array

Comment: @joao2fast4u That cleared up the error just fine. Funny thing is I tried that earlier this morning and got nothing. I probably had another part of it wrong somewhere. Does the rest of this look good though as far as getting it displaying the data from the string array?

Comment: I'm also curious about the placement of my addListenerOnSpinnerSelection(); Is it fine where its currently at?

Comment: @joao2fast4u Also, with these changes, my app no longer crashes, but the list does not get populated by my string array. It still has the dummy entries from my strings.xml

Comment: You have to call spinner.setAdapter(adapter); before addListenerOnSpinnerSelection(); I think your addListenerOnSpinnerSelection(); is in the right place.

Comment: @joao2fast4u Is my setting the entries in the .xml file to dummy entries a problem or would they just be overwritten by my assigning the names array to the spinner?

Comment: When I click the spinner on my device after removing the android:entries line in my xml, I get this in my logcat: Attempted to finish an input event but the input even receiver has already been disposed.

Comment: call spinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() directly. You don't need a method just to call another one.

Comment: In wich line are you getting that error message? See this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19832963/catching-an-event-when-spinner-drop-down-is-dismissed

Comment: @joao2fast4u That error is not giving a line. It is showing in the verbose log and just says W/InputEventReceiver: Attempted to finish an input even but....