# Check if AnimatorSet has finished animation?

Tags: android, animation, objectanimator

I'm trying to animate buttons with fade in animation using `AnimatorSet`

> `Button fades in > Click button > Remaining buttons fade out`

So in order to do this, I want to set the `onClickListner after the animation is completed`, but that doesn't seem to work. Clicking a button in the middle of the animation `triggers the onClick action`:

```
setQuestion = new AnimatorSet();           
setQuestion.playSequentially(fadeinAnimationQ,fadeinAnimation1,fadeinAnimation2,fadeinAnimation3,fadeinAnimation4,fadeinAnimation5);
setQuestion.start();
```

This is the method that checks `if the animation has finished`.

```
private void checkAnimation() {
    while (true) {
        // Check if animation has ended
        if (setQuestion.isRunning() == false) {
            assignListners();
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Here is how you can add an AnimatorListner:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7274001/how-do-i-do-something-when-an-animation-finishes

Answer (score 54, accepted):

You can set an [AnimatorListener](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/animation/Animator.AnimatorListener.html) on fadeinAnimation5.
This will give you an onAnimationEnd callback.

```
fadeinAnimation5.addListener(new AnimatorListener() {

            @Override
            public void onAnimationStart(Animator animation) {
                // ...
            }

            @Override
            public void onAnimationRepeat(Animator animation) {
                // ...
            }

            @Override
            public void onAnimationEnd(Animator animation) {
                // ...
            }

            @Override
            public void onAnimationCancel(Animator animation) {
                // ...
            }
        });
```

Or, as suggested by [slott](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21854027/check-if-animatorset-has-finished-animation/21854162#comment66423578_21854162) use an [AnimatorListenerAdapter](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/animation/AnimatorListenerAdapter.html)

```
fadeinAnimation5.addListener(new AnimatorListenerAdapter() {

    @Override
    public void onAnimationEnd(Animator animation) {
        // ...
    }
}
```

Comment: If you do not need all the events you could go for AnimatorListenerAdapter which keeps things a bit more simple.

Comment: A note of warning I fell for. The onAnimationEnd callback is called both if the animation finished OR was cancelled. To get notified only when the animation finished, use withEndAction(Runnable ) instead.

Answer (score 2):

I was having a similar problem and here is how I solved it:

```
private void crossFadeAnimation(final View fadeInTarget, final View fadeOutTarget, long duration){
    AnimatorSet mAnimationSet = new AnimatorSet();
    ObjectAnimator fadeOut = ObjectAnimator.ofFloat(fadeOutTarget, View.ALPHA,  1f, 0f);
    fadeOut.addListener(new Animator.AnimatorListener() {
        @Override
        public void onAnimationStart(Animator animation) {
        }

        @Override
        public void onAnimationEnd(Animator animation) {
            fadeOutTarget.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        }

        @Override
        public void onAnimationCancel(Animator animation) {
        }

        @Override
        public void onAnimationRepeat(Animator animation) {
        }
    });
    fadeOut.setInterpolator(new LinearInterpolator());

    ObjectAnimator fadeIn = ObjectAnimator.ofFloat(fadeInTarget, View.ALPHA, 0f, 1f);
    fadeIn.addListener(new Animator.AnimatorListener() {
        @Override
        public void onAnimationStart(Animator animation) {
            fadeInTarget.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        }

        @Override
        public void onAnimationEnd(Animator animation) {}

        @Override
        public void onAnimationCancel(Animator animation) {}

        @Override
        public void onAnimationRepeat(Animator animation) {}
    });
    fadeIn.setInterpolator(new LinearInterpolator());
    mAnimationSet.setDuration(duration);
    mAnimationSet.playTogether(fadeOut, fadeIn);
    mAnimationSet.start();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can actually set a listener to the AnimatorSet directly since AnimatorSet inherits from Animator.  Here's some code:

```
import android.animation.Animator;

        AnimatorSet setQuestion = new AnimatorSet();
        setQuestion.playSequentially(fadeinAnimationQ,fadeinAnimation1,fadeinAnimation2,fadeinAnimation3,fadeinAnimation4,fadeinAnimation5);
        setQuestion.addListener(new Animator.AnimatorListener() {
            @Override
            public void onAnimationStart(Animator animator) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onAnimationEnd(Animator animator) {
            // !! turn on your onClickListener here !!
            }

            @Override
            public void onAnimationCancel(Animator animator) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onAnimationRepeat(Animator animator) {

            }
        });
        setQuestion.start();
```