# check if progressbar animation is done android

Tags: android, animation

I need to check when the progressbar animation is done.
Then i need to do something.

I already have this:

```
private ObjectAnimator progressAnimator;

mProgressBar = (ProgressBar)findViewById(R.id.progressbar);
mProgressBar.setMax(1000);
progressAnimator = ObjectAnimator.ofInt(mProgressBar, "progress", 1000, 0);
progressAnimator.setDuration(10000);
progressAnimator.start();
```

How to check if this animation is done??

Comment: [How do I do something when an animation finishes?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7274001/how-do-i-do-something-when-an-animation-finishes)

Comment: thanks but could someone give me an example inside my code?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use addListener() method:

```
     progressAnimator.addListener(new Animator.AnimatorListener() {
            @Override
            public void onAnimationStart(Animator animation) {   
            }
            @Override
            public void onAnimationEnd(Animator animation) {
               //here animation finished
            }

            @Override
            public void onAnimationCancel(Animator animation) {
            }

            @Override
            public void onAnimationRepeat(Animator animation) {
            }
        });
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use:

```
if(progressAnimator.isRunning()){
    //Code here
}
```